# Stream tweets to SQL database Akka

Tags: scala, twitter, twitter4j, akka-stream

Is this possible to write tweets in real-time into some relational database (like MySQL or PostgreSQL) without the usage of Spark in Scala? Instead, I would like to user streaming module of Akka.

I would really appreciate some resources and advice on this topic.

**EDIT:** I have tried to connect to Twitter API and I used Twitter4J to get some tweets and filter them. Now I am on the stage where I want to write extracted tweets into the database instead of writing to the console.

```
class Counter extends StatusAdapter{
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("EmojiTrends")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher
  implicit val LoggingAdapter =
    Logging(system, classOf[Counter])

  val overflowStrategy = OverflowStrategy.backpressure
  val bufferSize = 1000
  val statusSource = Source.queue[Status](
    bufferSize,
    overflowStrategy
  )

  val sink: Sink[Any, Future[Done]] = Sink.foreach(println)
  val flow: Flow[Status, String, NotUsed] = Flow[Status].map(status => status.getText)
  val graph = statusSource via flow to sink
  val queue = graph.run()

  override def onStatus(status: Status) = 
    Await.result(queue.offer(status), Duration.Inf)
}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. Please add more specifics and context into what you have already tried.

Comment: @AndyPiper I have updated my question

Comment: did you find the solution? can you please share it?